# Android Contacts Content URI HAS_PHONE_NUMBER not working as explained in documentation, please guide

Tags: android

I am trying to run the following code.

```
  ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                null, null, null, null);
        if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
            while (cur.moveToNext()) {
                  String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                  String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                  if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(
                        cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
                     Cursor pCur = cr.query(
                               ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                               null,
                               ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?",
                               new String[]{id}, null);
                     while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                         String phoneNo = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                         Toast.makeText(NativeContentProvider.this, "Name: " + name + ", Phone No: " + phoneNo, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                     }
                    pCur.close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

So basically I query Contacts.URI and then on the basis of returned data if HAS_PHONE_NUMBER >0 , I query Phone.URI.

When I run this on my phone, I see 3 contacts that get displayed, who don't have corresponding entry in PHONE content URI. These 3 contacts have phone number for sure, as I can see those phone numbers when I go to my phone dialer screen.

How this is possible for a contact to have HAS_PHONE_NUMBER > 0 and still not have corresponding row in PHONE Content URI. Is it not weired, and how to get rid of this.

Please let me know.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This small method gets the contacts based on an option string search parameter. It only fetches contacts that include phone numbers.

```
private Cursor getContactsCursor(String searchPattern){
    String selection = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " LIKE ? and " + ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + " > 0 ";
    String queryArguments = "%" + searchPattern + "%";
    String[] selectionArgs = new String[] { queryArguments };
    String sortOrder = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";

    return getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);
}
```